# JSONP result and running multiple functions on that data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jsonp

I am sending a JSONP request and in the result set is three methods.

The problem is after the first function executes, the rest are not.

```
function syncData(jsonData){
    alert('1');
    getUnreadNotifications(jsonData.getUnreadNotifications);
    alert('2');
    getActiveCL(jsonData.getActiveCL);
    alert('3');
    getActiveCLI(jsonData.getActiveCLI);
}
```

It will only alert 1. Then stops. Here are the functions... what am I doing wrong?

```
function getActiveCL(jsonData2){

    var list =$('#ul-cl');
    list.empty();
    var htmldata = '';

    jQuery.each(jsonData2, function() {
        htmldata += '<li data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-li-has-count ui-corner-top"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="#consideration-list-id-' + this.id + '" class="ui-link-inherit">Table ' + this.table + ' - ' + this.guest_name + ' ' + this.created + ' <span class="ui-li-count ui-btn-up-c ui-btn-corner-all">' + this.items + '</span></a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-r ui-icon-shadow"></span></div></li>';
    });
    list.append(htmldata);
    list.listview();
    list.listview('refresh');
    $('a[href="#consideration-list-listing"] .ui-li-count').html(jsonData2.length); 
}
function getActiveCLI(jsonData){
    var lists =$('[id^="ul-consideration-list-id-"]');
    lists.empty();
    alert(jsonData);
    jQuery.each(jsonData, function() {
        var list = $('#ui-consideration-list-id-'+ this.cl_id);
        //timeElapsed = elapsedpretty(this.created);
        alert(list.size());         
        var htmldata = '<li data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-li-has-count ui-corner-top"><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li"><div class="ui-btn-text"><a href="#item-id-' + this.item_id + '" class="ui-link-inherit">' + this.name + '</a></div><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info ui-icon-shadow"></span></div></li>';
        list.append(htmldata);
    });
    lists.listview();
    lists.listview('refresh');
}

function getUnreadNotifications(jsonData){
    // Build Lists
    var appendData = '';
    var list = $('#message-ul');
    var lastID = 0;
    var messageCount = [];
    var currentVal = parseInt($('.nav a[href="#message-listing"] .ui-li-count').html());
    jQuery.each(jsonData, function() {
        appendData +='<li id="mid-'+this.id+'" data-theme="a" class="ui-btn ui-btn-up-b ui-btn-icon-right ui-li-has-arrow ui-li ui-li-has-count ui-corner-top ui-li-static ui-body-a" ><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert ui-icon-shadow"></span><div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li  ui-li-static ui-body-a"><div class="ui-btn-text">Table '+this.table+' - '+this.created+'</div></div></li>';
        lastID = this.id;
    });
    // Prepend new messages

    list.prepend($(appendData).hide()).children().slideDown();
    $('a[href="#message-listing"] .ui-li-count').html(currentVal + jsonData.length);
    // Set last checked id
    if(lastID !== 0) localStorage.setItem('last_message_id', lastID);

    list.listview();
    list.listview('refresh');
}
```

And finally the JSON. Tested it all in jsonlint and validates:

```
syncData({
    "getUnreadNotifications": [
        {
            "id": "98",
            "message_type_id": "2",
            "visit_id": "82",
            "active": "1",
            "created": "2011-10-07 13:42:21",
            "table": "2",
            "rvc_id": "2",
            "zone": "2",
            "seat": "1",
            "guest_name": "Foster Test"
        },
        {
            "id": "100",
            "message_type_id": "4",
            "visit_id": "82",
            "active": "1",
            "created": "2011-10-07 16:11:10",
            "table": "2",
            "rvc_id": "2",
            "zone": "2",
            "seat": "1",
            "guest_name": "Foster Test"
        },
        {
            "id": "101",
            "message_type_id": "5",
            "visit_id": "82",
            "active": "1",
            "created": "2011-10-07 16:11:10",
            "table": "2",
            "rvc_id": "2",
            "zone": "2",
            "seat": "1",
            "guest_name": "Foster Test"
        },
        {
            "id": "102",
            "message_type_id": "3",
            "visit_id": "82",
            "active": "1",
            "created": "2011-10-07 16:11:11",
            "table": "2",
            "rvc_id": "2",
            "zone": "2",
            "seat": "1",
            "guest_name": "Foster Test"
        },
        {
            "id": "103",
            "message_type_id": "2",
            "visit_id": "82",
            "active": "1",
            "created": "2011-10-08 13:22:57",
            "table": "2",
            "rvc_id": "2",
            "zone": "2",
            "seat": "1",
            "guest_name": "Foster Test"
        },
        {
            "id": "104",
            "message_type_id": "4",
            "visit_id": "82",
            "active": "1",
            "created": "2011-10-08 13:22:57",
            "table": "2",
            "rvc_id": "2",
            "zone": "2",
            "seat": "1",
            "guest_name": "Foster Test"
        },
        {
            "id": "105",
            "message_type_id": "2",
            "visit_id": "82",
            "active": "1",
            "created": "2011-10-08 13:23:08",
            "table": "2",
            "rvc_id": "2",
            "zone": "2",
            "seat": "1",
            "guest_name": "Foster Test"
        }
    ],
    "getActiveCL": [
        {
            "id": "9",
            "visit_id": "82",
            "created": 1317949631,
            "items": "6",
            "table": "2",
            "guest_name": "Foster Test"
        }
    ],
    "getActiveCLI": [
        {
            "table": "2",
            "cl_id": "9",
            "item_id": "100010",
            "price": "4300",
            "name": "Anakena"
        },
        {
            "table": "2",
            "cl_id": "9",
            "item_id": "18027",
            "price": "5500",
            "name": "Chicken Shashlik"
        },
        {
            "table": "2",
            "cl_id": "9",
            "item_id": "18016",
            "price": "3500",
            "name": "Chicken Steak Burger"
        },
        {
            "table": "2",
            "cl_id": "9",
            "item_id": "18018",
            "price": "3700",
            "name": "Lamb Sausage Masala Pizza"
        },
        {
            "table": "2",
            "cl_id": "9",
            "item_id": "100370",
            "price": "4300",
            "name": "Lamole di Lamole - Chianti Classico D.O.C.G"
        },
        {
            "table": "2",
            "cl_id": "9",
            "item_id": "100460",
            "price": "4300",
            "name": "Morande Grand Reserve"
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the javascript console for errors?¿

Comment: Something is throwing an error in `getUnreadNotifications()`. You might want to put a breakpoint in there and step through it to see what the problem is.

Comment: I am looking in chrome inspector and safari inspector,however its not throwing any errors. Thats why im so confused, but ill dig into getUnread and see if its something in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TypeError`. You sure you're using an up-to-date version of jqm?

You're calling `list.listview();` but `list.listview` is probably undefined. So trying to invoke undefined as a function throws an error. Once the interpretor hits the error it stops executing, so the rest of the script including alerts won't be called.

Comment: Hrm, When I changed the list selector to an id from a class/descendant selector I think this problem came up. And I wasn't seeing an error for some reason in my console. Thanks for the help I really appreciate it. Now I gotta figure out whats up with my console :)

Comment: @Fostah, a pleasure. It does sound a bit fishy... If there were other libraries/dependencies installed I didn't use them when I ran the code, so maybe with your code the error is different. But again, only you could know - and the console is pretty much the only guide you have. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> what am I doing wrong?

Not looking at the error log in your JS console to find out what exception has been thrown...